# Boot-Repair hangs, possible alternative?

Tags: boot, grub-legacy

My overall goal is to dual boot Linux Mint and Windows 10. The motherboard is legacy bios only.

Firstly I installed Linux Mint then Windows 10 on a secondary partition.
Because I forgot to make a separate boot partition... I moved everything 1000MB to the right, and created a ext4 boot partition at the beginning of sda.
Running boot repair on a live Ubuntu USB with the options:

- Separate /boot partition: sda4 (the first partition on disk)
- GRUB Legacy (figured that was for legacy bios)
- Reinstall GRUB (default)
- Unhide boot menu: 10s (default)

Boot Repair hangs at `Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel sda1 (ins). This may require several minuets...`

I have let this running overnight, the process is still running. I have done a reboot and tried again, let the process run for 3 days. Nothing different.

Boot Info Summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17678629/

*I have had gparted open at the same time, assuming that wouldn't have an affect.*

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue today. Digging through `boot-repair` tool logs I've found this error:

```
gui-actions-purge.sh: line 441: ${APTTYP[$USRPART]} ${INSTALLTYP[$USRPART]} ${YESTYP[$USRPART]} linux${$KERNELTOREINST}-generic linux-headers-generic: bad substitution
```

The logs are stored in the  `\var\log\boot-sav\log\YYYY-MM-DD__HHhMMboot-repairXX\boot-repair.log` file.

The package `linux${$KERNELTOREINST}-generic` doesn't look like a valid package. It probably should be just `linux-generic`.

So I've modified `\usr\share\boot-sav\gui-actions-purge.sh`, replacing line `441`:

```
local COMMAND="${APTTYP[$USRPART]} ${INSTALLTYP[$USRPART]} ${YESTYP[$USRPART]} linux${$KERNELTOREINST}-generic linux-headers-generic"
```

with:

```
local COMMAND="${APTTYP[$USRPART]} ${INSTALLTYP[$USRPART]} ${YESTYP[$USRPART]} linux-generic linux-headers-generic"
```

and restarted `boot-repair` from taskbar menu.

It worked OK and fixed my boot issues, restoring grub on my cloned disk.

#### Quick how-to

1. Boot `Boot-Repair` as usual, but close autostarted `boot-repair` tool
2. Open terminal from taskbar menu
3. Type `sudo su -` to get root shell
4. Type `leafpad &`
5. Text-editor will open. Open `\usr\share\boot-sav\gui-actions-purge.sh` file with it.
6. Find

   ```
   local COMMAND="${APTTYP[$USRPART]} ${INSTALLTYP[$USRPART]} ${YESTYP[$USRPART]} linux${$KERNELTOREINST}-generic linux-headers-generic"
   ```
7. Replace with:

   ```
   local COMMAND="${APTTYP[$USRPART]} ${INSTALLTYP[$USRPART]} ${YESTYP[$USRPART]} linux-generic linux-headers-generic"
   ```
8. Save file, close `Leafpad`
9. Leave root terminal open, you will need it later, as `boot-repair` will ask you to run some commands.
10. Run `boot-repair` from taskbar menu and follow it's instructions.

Comment: Made the change and still getting the same output.
Searched for other peoples experiences and found [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows#comment780735_182863) stating that you cannot use a legacy bios system. And the following comment suggests that I may need the live os in legacy?

Comment: @Harry Well, in my case it was legacy all the way down - it worked OK. Could you post `boot-repair.log`? I've used TeamViewer to get it: `wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb && apt-get install ./teamviewer_i386.deb && teamviewer`

Answer (score 0):

My general approach to these quagmires is image the disks involved, then just start fresh.

Not technically helpful I know, but my advice nonetheless.